# vim-go use environment file for :GoRun

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-go

When I use an IDE like Goland I'm able to set an environment file for the process when I run the program. I've done the following to get a similar result. I added the following to the init.vim.

```
" Function to source only if file exists {
function! SourceIfExists(file)
  if filereadable(expand(a:file))
    exe 'source' a:file
  endif
endfunction

:command! GoRunEnv :call SourceIfExists(".env") | GoRun
:cabbrev GoRun GoRunEnv
:command! GoTestEnv :call SourceIfExists(".env") | GoTest
:cabbrev GoTest GoTestEnv
```

Every time I run `:GoRun` or `:GoTest`, all variables defined in the file  `.env` will be added to the process. The `.env` file has to look like the following:

```
let $HUHU = "What ever"
```

Is there a way to include a `normal` environment file like this?

```
HUHU=What ever
```

Maybe I'm completely on the wrong way an there is a better approach?